# plpython setup windows 8

Tags: postgresql, plpython

I am trying to set up plypython on the following system:

Windows 8.1

PostgreSQL 9.2 64-bit

Python 2.7.05

When I run:

```
CREATE EXTENSION plpython2u;
```

I get:

```
 ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/plpython2.dll": %1     is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Is this a problem with the set-up or the .dll?
Cheers.

Comment: Don't copy and paste questions between sites. Please delete the other one here (http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/87625/12379) it's off topic on gis.stackexchange.com . If you want to "move" a question, ask a mod to do do it by flagging the question. Or delete the old one. Or at least link between them, or you waste everyone's time and fragment the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you've installed the 32-bit plpython DLL, or you have 32-bit DLLs on the `PATH` that are causing issues.

Take a look with the 64-bit version of Dependency Walker (`depends.exe`), see what it reports. If it notes that it's a 32-bit DLL, or complains that it's linking to 32-bit DLLs, you know you've got issues there. It'll also report any missing/broken DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that PostgreSQL 92 does not work with Python2 out of the box.  You need to use Python3.

It *may* be possible to build 9.2 in such a way that it works with python 2.7.  I don't know how to do that.